# Modbus CRC calculation using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, modbus

I tried to calculate CRC using VB.Net but the value is different.

Example if I use `05 03 0B D3 00 01` data CRC code should be `76 53` but I get `B6 45`

This is my VB.Net code.

```
Private Function CRC(data As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim crcfull As UShort = &HFFFF
    Dim crchigh As Byte = &HF, crclow As Byte = &HFF
    Dim crclsb As Char
    Dim result As Byte() = New Byte(1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To (data.Length) - 3
        crcfull = CUShort(crcfull Xor data(i))
        For j As Integer = 0 To 7
            crclsb = ChrW(crcfull And &H1)
            crcfull = CUShort((crcfull >> 1) And &H7FFF)
            If Convert.ToInt32(crclsb) Then
                crcfull = CUShort(crcfull Xor &HA001)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    crchigh = CByte((crcfull >> 8) And &HFF)
    crclow = CByte(crcfull And &HFF)
    Return New Byte(1) {crclow, crchigh}
End Function
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have the algorithm that it is supposed to follow?

Comment: Found something very similar [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?777161-Auto-calcul-CRC-for-modbus-interface-device). Though someone further down provided a different algorithm he has been using for a while. Might be a good thing to try

Answer (score 0):

You should turn option strict on, you would see that this line has a problem.

```
If Convert.ToInt32(crclsb) Then
```

I'm not sure what it is supposed to do, but you can't do an If statement with an integer, it has to be a Boolean.

Comment: In vb.net any non-zero integer will be considered true. The line is the same as `If crclsb <> 0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a VB expert, I do mostly C, C++ and C#, but I think it was one of your conversions which I don't think are needed.  This works for me:

```
Function CRC16(data As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim crcfull As UInt16 = &HFFFF
    Dim crchigh As Byte, crclow As Byte
    Dim crclsb As Byte

    For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1
        crcfull = crcfull Xor data(i)

        For j As Integer = 0 To 7
            crclsb = crcfull And &H1
            crcfull = crcfull >> 1

            If (crclsb <> 0) Then
                crcfull = crcfull Xor &HA001
            End If
        Next
    Next

    crchigh = (crcfull >> 8) And &HFF
    crclow = crcfull And &HFF
    Return New Byte(1) {crclow, crchigh}
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but in case anyone is interested I believe the code is correct. The challenge is the way the code is being called.

The following test demonstrates why B6 45 was being returned rather than 76 53.

```
Private Sub Test_CRC()
    'A test demo to verify vb.net CRC code

    Dim data() As Byte

    'a) Original test data - note 6 bytes only
    '   using 05 03 0B D3 00 01
    data = {&H5, &H3, &HB, &HD3, &H0, &H1}
    CRC_so(data)
    'Returns: B6 45 - decimal 182 69

    'b) Full test data sample - full 8 bytes, last two set to zero
    data = {&H5, &H3, &HB, &HD3, &H0, &H1, &H0, &H0}
    CRC_so(data)
    'Returns: 76 53 - decimal 118 83

End Sub
```

There are two options to using the code. Either:

a)  Submit an 8-byte data array to the function, filling last two bits with zero or

b)  Change the code to consider only 6 bytes by changing the line

```
For i As Integer = 0 To (data.Length) – 3   'This line is designed for 8-byte data
```

to

```
For i As Integer = 0 To (data. Length) - 1  'This line is designed for 6-byte data
```

I hope this is of assistance.